# Rewrite URL path with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to use Lamdba@Edge to rewrite the next URL path:

```
https://example.com/app OR https://example.com/app/ TO https://example.com/app/index.html
https://example.com/app/#/test123 TO https://example.com/app/index.html#/test123
```

Using the official documentation I wrote the following Python Lambda function, but I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    if request in ('https://example.com/app', 'https://example.com/app/'):
        request = "https://example.com/app/index.html"
    else:
        request = request.replace("/#/","/index.html#/")
    return request
```

Comment: what error are you getting?